# Can an instance of a class be created for testing without calling the constructor?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

Is it possible to instantiate a class with a complex constructor without mocking or calling its constructor? This would be useful because the unit test class shouldn't need to change every time a new dependency was added to the service.

Mocking the service solves the problem by creating a new implementation of the class, with empty method overrides, but this isn't an instance of the implementation. This is a problem because any time a method in the mocked service is called, Mockito has to be told to call the real method. Instead, an actual implementation of the service would be preferred.

For example:

```
class ComplexService {
    private Service service1;
    private Service service2;
    private Service service3;
    private Service service4;
    private Service service5;

    ComplexConstructor(Service service1, Service service2, Service service3, Service service4, Service service5) {
        this.service1 = service1;
        this.service2 = service2;
        this.service3 = service3;
        this.service4 = service4;
        this.service5 = service5;
    }

    boolean methodToTest() {
        return service1.get();
    }
}
```

In the unit test class, is it possible to have an instantiation of a implementation without having to call its constructor?

```
public class ComplexConostructorTest {
    private ComplexConstructor complexConstructor;
    private Service serviceMock;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        /*
         Somehow create implementation of complexConstructor
         without calling constructor

         . . .
          */

        // Mock dependency
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(complexConstructor, 
                "service1", 
                serviceMock = Mockito.mock(Service.class));
    }

    @Test
    public void service1Test() {
        when(serviceMock.get())
                .thenReturn(true);

        assertTrue(complexConstructor.methodToTest());
    }
}
```

**Edit**

It is possible using reflection, I was hoping there was a built in way in JUnit or Mockito to achieve the same thing. Here is how to do it using reflection.

```
@Before
public void init() {
    Constructor<?> constructor = ComplexConstructor.class.getConstructors()[0];
    complexConstructor = (ComplexConstructor) constructor.newInstance(new Object[constructor.getParameterCount()]);

    // Mock dependency
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(complexConstructor,
            "service1",
            serviceMock = Mockito.mock(Service.class));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, as far as I know, but you can simply add a simpler Constructor to your class and use that for testing. On the other hand, if the test tests the object in a state that is different to what it will be in the app, I'm not sure how good such a test would be.

Comment: It's definitely possible. I have been able to do it using reflection. I was hoping there was something built into JUnit or Mockito that would do it for me. I will edit my question to reflection how it's done manually. Also, I think it's important to write testable code, but writing code for a test is something I resist.

Comment: Even with reflection you only can invoke an existing Constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you probably don't want to:

```
ComplexConstructor partialMock =
    Mockito.mock(ComplexConstructor.class, CALLS_REAL_METHODS);
```

This ["partial mock"](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.24.5/org/mockito/Mockito.html#16) instance will not have its constructor or field initializers called, but all calls to the system under test will invoke the class's real behavior. (Technically the class will also have its `equals` and `hashCode` overridden for Mockito's purposes, and the class will be a generated subclass of ComplexConstructor instead of ComplexConstructor itself.)

In this way, you can be insulated from the constructor, but because you are suppressing an arbitrary subset of the class-under-test's behavior it is much more difficult to *determine exactly what you're testing* in order to *be confident the system works because the test passes*. That should be your main goal in testing, and it may be difficult to achieve that with partial mocks. Colleagues or collaborators may rightly observe that *you shouldn't mock your system under test* for exactly this reason.

Though personally I don't think it's wrong or unexpected for you to need to change your unit tests to supply mocks when needed, you could create a factory separate from your test that supplies testing instances of ComplexConstructor, or consider using a dependency injection framework that automatically supplies mocks to your system under test.

Answer (score 0):

You can create helper methods as part of your test code, for example some factory methods with descriptive names that construct the object.  For example, `make_default_ComplexService` and more the like, just as needed by your tests.  The tests could then use these methods, and if the constructor changes, you will in many cases only have to update the helper methods and not all of the tests.  This approach is generic enough to also separate your test from drastic changes like turning the "constructor with parameters" approach into the "non-argument constructor with lots of setters" approach.

This approach will reduce maintenance effort for your tests, you will still use the original constructor (because it is called by the factory) rather than some fake constructor, and your test code might even be more readable than with the direct constructor's calls if the factory methods' names are well chosen.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are mixing up several terms and concepts. Let me help you understand them better.

> This would be useful because the unit test class shouldn't need to change every time a new dependency was added to the service.

Your class has a number of dependencies, that are provided via the constructor. If you are writing unit test your aim is **only** to test this dependent class, all dependencies should be mocked. That's why it is called **unit** testing. This means that with every new dependency of your class the test should be updated by adding new mock and its mocked behaviour.

> Mockito has to be told to call the real method. Instead, an actual implementation of the service would be preferred.

Consider integration tests, in this case, you can mock only some amount of dependencies while others will work as intended or "real" until you mock them of course. However, if you want just to avoid supporting tests then it is not the right approach.

Please don't try to hack your tested class from your test by reflection. This can lead to wrong test results, waste of time and overall disappointment :) Mocking libraries like PowerMock and JMockit provide any kind of hacks, like ones you've tried to implement yourself and are in general too powerful.

> With Great Power Comes Great Responsibility

Answer (score -1):

You could add a parameterless constructor to your class and create setter for all your fields.

```
class ComplexService {
    private Service service1;
    private Service service2;
    private Service service3;
    private Service service4;
    private Service service5;

    public ComplexService(){
      super();
    }
    ...

    public void setService1(Service service1){
      this.service1 = service1;
    }
    //for other fields too
    ...
}
```

In your test you call it like:

```
myService = new ComplexService()
myService.setService1(service1);
...
```

Comment: I think it's important to write testable code, but writing implementation code for a test is something I resist. Creating a constructor that is only usable by a unit test isn't good practice.

Comment: @BenR I disagree about your "good practice" statement: Your test is a very important consumer of your code, and it's good practice to design your code based on its consumers. You do need to be careful about what public API you offer, but you can think of test access like a diagnostics port on your car or test points on a circuit board: Clearly-marked, unobtrusive, and important for engineering reusable and reliable systems.